# How to calculate the current value of depreciated asset?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm aware of various depreciation formulas in google sheets, but to me it seems like non of them provide and cumulative value. So if I wanted to calculate the current value of a car bought 6 months ago, I'd have to have multiple rows calculating depreciation per month, and then I'd have to sum the depreciation over months (cells). Is there a way to put everything in one cell? Example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u3py5XG9IPBAMQXGmG0q-kyg60fxJ72Gy8C90Za1FTg

Columns A:F is working fine, but I want to be able to be able to have a list of multiple assets with todays (depriciated) value, like in columns H:P .

Any idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: Will the VDB function work for you?  You enter VDB(cost, salvage, life, start_period, end_period, [factor], [no_switch]).  Specify start_period as zero, and end period as the number of years (or fractions) that have passed, and the result is the total depreciation over that time period.  It gives a result between DDB and SYD.                                   
          So Purchase Price - VDB(...) is current asset value.                                       
            Hope this helps.  I'm sure there are other options...

Comment: Edit to above comment: The VDB function should default to give the same results as DDB but you can adjust the rate.

Comment: Hey kirkg, yeah, that will do the trick - thank you.

Comment: Mara, to help others in the future with a similar question, if VDB works for you, can you check the answer below as having answered your question.  Or if it hasn't, let us know, and someone will come up with something else... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is very brief, I want to record the comment that helped answer this question.

Will the [VDB function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9199424?hl=en) work for you?

You enter:
VDB(cost, salvage, life, start_period, end_period, [factor], [no_switch]).

So Purchase Price - VDB(...) is the current asset value, after a specific period of time, of the asset's lifespan.

Specify start_period as zero, and end period as the number of years (or fractions) that have passed, and the result is the total depreciation over that time period. It defaults to give a DDB ([Double Declining Balance depreciation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093163?hl=en)) answer, but the rate (factor) can be modified.  Hope this helps. I'm sure there are other options